# Count the number of images uploded on the website

Tags: wp-query, images, attachments, count

I mention "full website" because I don't need the number of attachments on one post (as answered in many questions). I basically need a function that returns the number of uploaded images (attached and unattached) on the website, excluding non-image files.

I've done some research, but there isn’t any direct function that counts only the images. What is the most simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a handy [built-in function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_attachments/), namely `wp_count_attachments()`.

We can filter out images with `wp_count_attachments( $mime_type = 'image' )` that returns an object like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [image/gif] => 9
    [image/jpeg] => 121
    [image/png] => 20
    [image/x-icon] => 6
    [trash] => 0
)
```

So we can use the one-liner:

```
$count = array_sum( (array) wp_count_attachments( $mime_type = 'image' ) );
```

for the total number of images.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I know is:

```
global $wpdb ;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'" ;

$count = (int) $wpdb->get_var ($sql) ;
```

You could also use WP_Query, altho doing so is more expensive:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => 0,
    ) ;
$attatchments = new WP_Query ($args) ;

$count = $attatchments->found_posts ;
```

**note:** setting `'posts_per_page' => 0` and reading `found_posts` is an optimization when using WP_Query in cases like this that I just learned from the answer to another question here on WPSE a few days ago...I don't remember which question it was, otherwise I'd credit the author for the tip.